# Any way to add a UIButton to a UITabBar to be tied to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a circular button above one of my tabs, but it doesn't reappear or disappear when I go to pushToViewController using a navigation controller in one of my tabs when using:

```
aViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Comment: is that button part of the tab bar or on it's own? if not you could just hide it when you hide the tab bar. also, it wont appear in other view controller because it's not part of the root view controller.

Comment: I want to make it part of the tab bar but how?

Comment: How do i make it hidden and how do I make it return

Comment: You have to make your own custom tab bar in that case. There are multiple ways to do this, you can even download some free customizable tab bars out there like: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tab+bar